# Unable to use Flexbox Horizontal property Effectively

Tags: scroll, flexbox, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
 .flex{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 320px;
    gap: 4px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 2px solid rgb(11, 11, 11);
    }
   .class {
    min-width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    border:2px solid black;
    border-radius:4px;
    }
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="flex">
        <div class="class"></div>
        <div class="class"></div>
        <div class="class"></div>
        <div class="class"></div>
        <div class="class"></div>
        <div class="class"></div>
        <div class="class"></div>
        <div class="class"></div>
        <div class="class"></div>
        <div class="class"></div>
        <div class="class"></div>
        <div class="class"></div>
        <div class="class"></div>
        <div class="class"></div>
        <div class="class"></div>
        <div class="class"></div>
        <div class="class"></div>
       
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

now the problem I am facing is that I want all these 17 items that are placed in parent container to scroll horizontally through parent container but only 12 item appears when scrolling horizontally not all 17.
please Help!`

Answer (score 0):

Deleting

```
justify-content: center;
```

in the styling of `.flex` seems to be solving your issue.

Since your div is supposed to be a scrollable container, I don't think you need `justify-content`, however, if you do wish to use it, I'd recommend checking out documentation: [MDN justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).

Comment: Thanks  it finally worked.